# Nginx on Windows using WSGI

Tags: django, windows-xp, nginx

now that i've decided to use Nginx as my favourite webserver to deploy Django, i got some "mist":

1. i'm on Windows, that said, i got errors when i try to use Django as FastCGI, it seems that Flup dont load! it give me errors! and from the website, flup is not a good friend of Windows:
   [check out here](http://trac.saddi.com/flup/wiki/FlupFaq#DoesflupworkunderWindows)
2. all tutorials that i've found says that ngnix is good when it's used as reverse proxy, i already asked this question, and this is why it seems that now i can use 100% ngnix.
3. i'll make my project on this, and i want to use something different than what is used in my university, they always use LAMP and i hate LAMP! i want something new! and something new and hot is Ngnix + Django ON WINDOWS!

---

so here is my question:
does really ngnix work on windows, alone, only ngnix to deploy a django project! i want please something for a total beginner coming from earth and speaking human language ^_^

- NB: please dont talk about IIS, i'll use a normal Windows XP pro to make my engineering project.
- NB2: what about this [nginx bug](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/05/blocking-requests-and-nginx-version-of.html) , has been fixed?

Comment: Nginx + Django on Windows is NOT new and hot. If anything I would say it is old and asking for trouble. Why do you hate LAMP? Instead of trying to shoe-horn Django and Nginx onto an old XP box, why not fire up a VM on that XP box running Ubuntu, Fedora or CentOS.